# optimal minimization algorithm for platou

Tags: optimization

Greeting, I'm trying to solve an optimization problem (minimization, to be specific).

My problem is that my function has one major plateau (see example image).
I'm using the optimization algorithms of scipy, and only basinhoppin actually solves the problem, but VERY slow.

Can you assist in finding a way to speed things up?
thx

[image]